# Is it a good design practice/necessary to put some capacitors next to the power connector on a PCB?

Tags: power, capacitor, pcb-design

I've seen some schematics that do this, and some that don't. Is it best practice to put some caps on the input power rail next to the power connector to smooth out any transients, or for some other purpose? Does it matter how the off board voltage is created (linear vs switching)?

Comment: It depends on use case. Sometimes the caps are for preventing incoming noise to board. Sometimes the caps are for preventing noise going out from the board.  And their presence is also detemined by if hot-plugging of input power is expected, and which end of the cable is being hot-plugged, the power supply or device end. Sometimes the caps at connector cause more problems than solve during hotplugging, unless properly managed. If you have a specific case, can you further define what the case is?

Comment: There will be no hot plugging. This PCB will remain in a chassis, powered by a linear AC/DC converter with a 15VDC output. The 15VDC will stepped down through a buck and LDOS to 5V and 3.3V to power some digital logics ICs.

Comment: Will the buck regulator be near power input connector?

Comment: It is a good practice BUT, ceramic capacitors on an input rail can be subject to input voltage overshoot transients when you plug in power. So consider tantalum or electrolytic or take advantage of a fuse or PTC as a series R for your ceramic Cap. Worst case you can add a series resistor for your ceramic cap to damp out any overshoot. Check out Linear Technology Application Note 88 (AN88-1). https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/an88f.pdf

Answer (score 6):

> Is it a good design practice/necessary to put some capacitors next to the power connector on a PCB?

Adding capacitors may help decouple your pcb from the power supply. That is often a good thing. However, there are two caveats that I would mention.

1. Added capacitors will increase your inrush current. This may be an issue for your power supply.
2. Added capacitors will interact with the inductance in your power wires. This may cause ringing. It may be advisable to dampen this potential ringing by having a capacitor with a relatively high effective series resistance (ESR) such as an aluminum electrolytic. You may add a low ESR ceramic as well. However, if you add *only* a low ESR ceramic, you might also want to add a very low value resistor in series with it.

These concerns do not mean that a problem would definitely materialize if you added capacitance. They are just potential problems to be aware of.

Comment: Sometimes you can just ad a PTC or fuse, and the ESR of the PTC or fuse will provide adequate damping (or dampening if that is how you prefer to say it).

Answer (score 2):

Our standard practice is to put a couple of ~23 uF tantalums close to where the supply voltage(s) come into the board.  Then a bunch of 0.1 uF ceramics scattered across the board.

Our power supplies come up slowly in a controlled fashion, say 50 ms.  So inrush current is not a big concern.  All that capacitance is tracked and goes into the loop stability analysis for the power system.  See a typical arrangement below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example from a board measuring microvolt signals with megahertz bandwidths. I prefer to use choke inputs because those block the noise current, which can otherwise inductively couple to loops on the board. They also help with surge.

Power enters on the left. L2 is a fat bead core, optimized for "low" frequency (<50 MHz). Dissipation in the inductors and C10 (tantalum) is sufficient to prevent serious ringing.

[image]